# Having Several Units on Highcharts Spiderweb

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Can someone please let me know if it is technically possible to have a Spiderweb Chart with  5 different units yAxis some thing like this image. This is for cases that units are not same but can be a compered very fast.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The labels are displayed only on yAxis (which you have defaulty), but you have ability to use [Renderer](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.text) to add custom text.